# Send a plain text email with an embedded <a> tag in mailgun

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, mailgun

I am trying to embed an `<a>` link within the text of an email I'm sending through mailgun. What is the correct syntax?

```
RestClient.post "https://api:#{ENV['MAILGUN_SECRET']}"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/#{ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN']}/messages",
  :from => "Mailgun <mailgun@#{ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN']}>",
  :to => "#{@lead.email}",
  :subject => "Test",
  :text => "Here is the message, here(http://www.foo.com) is the link"
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you can send a "text" email with HTML you have to pick one
I like to send all my emails a HTML

This is how my mailer looks like:

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def email_method(post_id, lead_id)
    @post = Post.find(post_id)
    @lead = Lead.find(lead_id)
    mail(
        :from => "Email Sender<info@example.com>",
        :to =>   @lead.email,
        :reply_to => 'Email Sender<info@example.com>',
        :subject => "Test"
    )
  end
end
```

now this is the fun part. Create a folder called `SomeMailer` in `app/views` so you end up with `app/views/some_mailer`

now create a file in that directory called `email_method.html.erb` that contains your html like:

```
  Here is the message, here(<a href="http://www.foo.com"> foo.com </a>) is the link
```

I hope that this helps